# Can someone show a known good working function in Xojo 2014?

Tags: macos, function, syntax, realbasic, xojo

So.. I just downloaded Xojo 2014 for OS X, and up to this point have found it a pretty simple and effective development environment.

However, I've been trying to make a function or sub routine for 45 minutes. Every time I try following tutorials or the Xojo documentation I get the following error:

[image]

I've followed (even though I could be missing something) the directions here: http://docs.xojo.com/index.php/Function

Even though there is no full example in the documentation (bad development environment).

Also, in the screen shot is showing a sample function I copied and pasted off Xojo forums and is supposed to work.  I'm not  a programming newb per say, but more an Xojo newb. I've also had experiences with silly bugs in RealStudio in the past.

Can someone maybe point out what I could be missing?

Answer (score 6):

You cannot use the `Function`, `Sub`, `End Function`, or `End Sub` lines in the method editor. Doing so will cause a syntax error because method declarations are automatically added by the IDE based on the values you enter into the method editor's name, parameters, and return type fields.

e.g.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

as said,

Function, Sub, End Function, or End Sub is done for you,

you can do 'exit sub' if nothing need to be returned, else just return a proper value

like some events need a true or false, so if you need the exit the function, just return false

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add inline functions within your Xojo code. You add methods to your project items these ways:

- Insert->Method
- "+" button on editor toolbar, then Method
- Insert button on main toolbar, then Method
- Option-Command-M (on OS X)